# JavaScript if else regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have got an issue with a small Java Script application. One of my friend need to transfer "regex" statment to some value. To be sure that onyone will understand me - below is the example:

> test = $[T1?$[T2?$T3|$T4]$T5|$T6]

Fist step:

> if T1 = empty -> test = T6
>
> if T1 not empty -> test = $[T2?$T3|$T4]$T5

next step in case if T1 not empty:

> if T2 = empty -> test = T4 + T5
>
> if T2 not empty -> test = T3 + T5

Is it possible to do it in Java Script ? or maybe the easier will be to change the convension of the expresion? Is there any Java Script standard and not use the "[?|]" signs? All Tx are variable this is the reason why there are the $ characters.

Best regards,
K.

Comment: This will be quite tricky with regexes only, I'd suggest you write a parser.

Comment: Why do this in regex? You're using JavaScript... use that

Comment: how to use the JavaScript only for that? Of course there will be other different cases - this is one of the most nested:(

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
test = t1 ? (t2 ? t3 : t4) + t5 : t6;
```

Comment: yes exactly like you wrote. any idea how to implement it in Java Script?

Comment: That *is* JavaScript.